# Make [tag-alias-request] a synonym of [synonym-request]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, meta

Not a big deal maybe, but can we make [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) a synonym of
[synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request)?

There are 16 questions tagged [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) of which all were asked
in 2016.
The tag [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) was created in August 2016.

There are (currently) 1,026 questions tagged [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) of which
the oldest was asked in 2014 and the latest in 2021 (yesterday actually).
The tag [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) was created in April 2014.

The usage guidance (excerpt) of [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) reads:
*Use [...] when multiple tags should [...] redirect to the same tag [...].*

The usage guidance (excerpt) of [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) reads:
*A request to add one tag as the synonym of another tag.*

My suggestion: [tag-alias-request](/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request) (× 16)
→ [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) (× 1,026)

To the best of my understanding, these two tags serve the exact same purpose.
Or did I miss something?

**References:**

- [Questions tagged [tag-alias-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-alias-request)
- [Tag wiki of [tag-alias-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-alias-request/info)
- [Tag wiki revisions to [tag-alias-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/331989/revisions)
- [Usage guidance revisions to [tag-alias-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/331990/revisions)
- [Questions tagged [synonym-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request)
- [Tag wiki of [synonym-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonym-request/info)
- [Tag wiki revisions to [synonym-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250744/revisions)
- [Usage guidance revisions to [synonym-request]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250745/revisions)

Comment: Now that's Meta! Asking a synonym request for `[synonym-request]`

Comment: Yeah, I know. :-)

Comment: Points for being super meta! Regarding the proposal, though - the tag seems to be from the older days when "documentation" project existed. Also, there seems to be no mistagging happening, so shouldn't we just let the tag be?

Comment: @OlegValter, yes. That is what I meant with my starting phrase *Not a big deal maybe ...*. ~ * ~ I agree that as long as nobody starts using the old tag again there is nothing to worry about. On the other hand - if it is very easy to create the synonym, why not go ahead and do it? I might mention that [as late as year 2020 the concept "alias request" was used in three questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22alias%20request%22%20is%3aquestion). - Again, as long as the right tag is used, there is no problem.

Comment: I think we should just replace it with the new tag.

Comment: @Henke ‍♂️ maybe do a merge as TylerH suggested - thankfully the tag is not misused

Comment: @OlegValter, sure. I never understood the difference between "merging" and *making a synonym*. Or are they the same thing? I imagine making [tag:tag-alias-request] a synonym of [tag:synonym-request] would have as effect that [tag-alias-request] becomes **visually** replaced by [synonym-request] in those 16 questions (but "under the hood" [tag-alias-request] is still intact)? I am not the decision maker (I just raised the issue), but if "replacing the old tag with the new tag" is the same as making [tag-alias-request] a synonym of [synonym-request], then I will certainly accept such an answer.

Comment: @Henke - these actions are related, but differ quite a bit: tag *merge* requires a moderator to splice the two tags together (in which case a decision has to be made about which should remain), effectively "replacing" the tag. Tag *synonym* means making one tag an alias of another, your understanding is correct here (it stays in the system and can be chosen by askers, but is silently remapped to the parent tag + alias's info page redirects to parent's).

Comment: @OlegValter, thanks! Every day is an opportunity to learn something new. :-) ~ * ~ * ~ * ~ I will accept either action as an answer.

Comment: @Henke - NP, there is an abyss of meta info to find) Re:action - I do think no action is the best choice here - it is not semantically correct to put them on synonym-request Q&As. Aliasing is such a common term that I believe those who use it, refer to it in a general sense of the word. In any case, I think I recall a stance I support - that we deal away with tags that actively cause harm or have a very high misuse potential. Seems like [meta-tag:tag-alias-request]  is neither (an aside: you can refer to meta tags by "meta-tag" in commend markdown, or links are generated to the SO proper) :)

Comment: @OlegValter so is there any reason to merge tags instead of synonym-ing them? It sounds like they should have functionally the same user-visible result (except that if they are merged then the deleted tag can be recreated), and merging sounds both destructive and more work. Is it purely a historical thing, or is there any reason that's done anymore?

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey Not sure I follow? I am of the "nothing to do here" opinion and certainly prefer not merging them as [meta-tag:tag-alias-request] is a legacy tag for a feature of the sunsetted Documentation project. Since the tag does not actively cause harm (12 old questions and no mistagged synonym requests), we can simply leave it be